# If $n$ people throw $n$ dice, what's the probability that we find exactly $k$ 6's?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification

Let $n$ people hold $n$ dice, throwing all at once. What's the probability that we find exactly $k $  6's , $k \leq n$?

My approach is this experiment is equivalent to throwing the  dice successivly n times. So the probability we have exactly $k$ 6's  is :

$${n \choose k}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^k \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n-k}$$

Is my approach correct?

please help me with this question

Comment: Your approach is correct